# Blazor bunit test of radio buttons

Tags: blazor

I am writing a custom Blazor component that uses radio buttons to simulate a checkbox (don't ask why).
I've got this in the .razor file:

```
    <InputRadioGroup
        ResourceType="@CommonResourceType"
        class="form-control"
        id="@fieldIdentifier.FieldName"
        Name="@fieldIdentifier.FieldName"
        @bind-Value="this.RadioValue">

        <InputRadio class="btn-check" Id="@this.NameYes" Name="@fieldIdentifier.FieldName" Value=1 />
        <InputRadio class="btn-check" Id="@this.NameNo" Name="@fieldIdentifier.FieldName" Value=0 />
    </InputRadioGroup>
```

I want to write a unit test that confirms that the model gets updated:

```
        // Arrange
        using var context = CreateTestContext();
        TestModel model = new();
        var sut = context.Render(GetRenderFragment(model));

        // Act
        sut.Find("#YesElement").Click();

        // Assert
        sut.WaitForAssertion(() => model.IsTrue.Should().BeTrue());
```

The problem I have is that when the test clicks the element, it throws an exception to say that the element doesn't have a click handler, but it does have a changed handler.  How do I call the change handler (.Change(new ChangeEventArgs()) doesn't work).

The component works OK in a real form, I just need to test the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of your code that demonstrates the `Change` event working.

My page to test:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="mb-3">
    <InputRadioGroup id="radioteet" @bind-Value="this.model.RadioValue">
        <InputRadio class="form-check-input" id="radiotest1" Value="1" /><span class="form-check-label">Yes</span>
        <InputRadio class="form-check-input" id="radiotest2" Value="2" /><span class="form-check-label">Maybe</span>
    </InputRadioGroup>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre id="radiotestout">Value : @this.model.RadioValue</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private Model model = new() ;

    public class Model
    {
        public int RadioValue { get; set; } = 0;
    }
}
```

And my test which works:

```
        [Fact]
        public void ClickYes()
        {
            // Arrange
            var cut = RenderComponent<SO75988232.Pages.Index>();

            // Act - click radio button to select No
            cut.Find("#radiotest1").Change(new ChangeEventArgs());

            // Assert that the value is correct
            cut.Find("#radiotestout").InnerHtml.Equals("Value : 1");
        }
        [Fact]
        public void ClickMaybe()
        {
            // Arrange
            var cut = RenderComponent<SO75988232.Pages.Index>();

            // Act - click radio button to select No
            cut.Find("#radiotest2").Change(new ChangeEventArgs());

            // Assert that the value is correct
            cut.Find("#radiotestout").InnerHtml.Equals("Value : 2");
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That solution didn't work for me.  You need to pass the value from the radio button into the ChangeEventArgs that is sent to the Change event in your test.  Something like below.

```
        var eventArgs = new ChangeEventArgs();
        eventArgs.Value = "1";
        cut.Find("#radiotest1").Change(eventArgs);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).