# BUnit's IElement.Change not triggering onchange of a Blazor 6 InputSelect component

Tags: blazor, bunit

Consider the following use of `<InputSelect>` (Blazor 6):

Edited: added the  - yes, the drop-down is populated with a few values.

```
<InputSelect @bind-Value="Model.Partner" @onchange="@OnPartnerChange" id="Partner">
   @foreach (var aKVP in AllKVPs)
   {
      <option value="@aKVP.Key">@aKVP.Value</option>
   }
</InputSelect>
@code {
    private void OnPartnerChange(ChangeEventArgs arg)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In a bUnit test:

```
...
var partnerElement = componentUnderTest.Find("#Partner");
partnerElement.Change(new ChangeEventArgs { Value = "Select me" });
```

`OnPartnerChange` is not triggered by the test. What's the correct way to setup component interactions in a bUnit test, so that a drop-down value is selected, the Model is updated and OnChange runs?

(I tried locating the `<Option>` - doable - and doing options[x].Click() to no avail)

Answer (score 0):

### Updated [Net6.0] Answer

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<EditForm Model="@this.model">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <label>Change does run in Net 6</label>
            <InputSelect TValue=string class="form-select mb-2"
                         Value=@this.model.Value
                         ValueChanged=OnValueChanged
                         ValueExpression="() => this.model.Value">
                @if (this.model.Value is null)
                {
                    <option selected disabled> -- Select a Value -- </option>
                }
                <option value="France">France</option>
                <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                <option value="UK">UK</option>
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-3 p-1">
    <pre>Value: @this.model.Value</pre>
    <pre>Message: @this.Message</pre>
</div>

@code {
    public Model model = new();
    public string Message = string.Empty;

    private Task OnValueChanged(string? value)
    {
        this.model.Value = value;
        this.OnChange(value);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void OnChange(string? value)
    {
        this.Message = $"Changed at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public string? Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Original [Net7.0] Answer

It's not your test that's the problem it's your code.

You say "... the Model is updated and OnChange runs?"

Not true. In this code [I assume you have some options defined, otherwise there are no options to change]:

```cs
<InputSelect @bind-Value="Model.Partner" @onchange="@OnPartnerChange" id="Partner"/>
```

`onchange` never gets called because it's already assigned as part of the bind.

Here's a demo page that shows your configuration and it not getting called, and using `@bind-Value:after` which works.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <label>Change does not run</label>
        <InputSelect class="form-select mb-2"
                     @bind-Value=this.Value
                     @onchange=this.OnChange>
            @if (this.Value is null)
            {
                <option selected disabled> -- Select a Value -- </option>
            }
            <option value="France">France</option>
            <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
            <option value="UK">UK</option>
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <label>Change does run</label>
        <InputSelect class="form-select mb-2"
                     @bind-Value=this.Value
                     @bind-Value:after=this.OnChange>
            @if (this.Value is null)
            {
                <option selected disabled> -- Select a Value -- </option>
            }
            <option value="France">France</option>
            <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
            <option value="UK">UK</option>
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="bg-dark text-white m-3 p-1">
    <pre>Value: @this.Value</pre>
    <pre>Message: @this.Message</pre>
</div>

@code {
    public string? Value;
    public string Message = string.Empty;

    private void OnChange()
    {
        this.Message = $"Changed at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
    }
}
```

Here's a link to a recent answer on BUnit tests on input controls - [Blazor bunit test of radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75988232/blazor-bunit-test-of-radio-buttons/75988905#75988905)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, but this answer looks a bit like a ChatGPT hallucination :)

Comment: I apologise - I can see how my wording is not perfect, but in fact I wasn't saying OnChange works. I am asking how to correctly do it so it works. 

In the meanwhile I got the OnChange to work by using `EditContext.OnFieldChanged", but I am still interested to learn how to properly setup and test the OnChange of InputSelect. 

Also I updated my question to show that I am stuck with Blazor 6 and also added the options I had omitted for brevity

Comment: [Jesting and polite]  Be careful about suggesting answers are `ChatGPT` when they aren't: that's the sort of comment that will get you a black eye!

Comment: Said that with a smile, after I tried your code in my app - didn't work/didn't compile, blamed my .net version (6), but then in BlazorFiddle - didn't work/didn't compile.

Comment: There are a few issues at the moment on 7.0 with binding and the Razor Compiler - it depends on the version number whether it will compile or not.  Anyway, of no concern to you are you're on 6.0.  I've updated my answer to include code that will work in 6.0 that uses the `Value` and `Callback` parameters directly.  Let me know if you can get that working.

Comment: Using `EditContext.OnFieldChanged` is not the way to go.  It's like dialling International to speak to the person at the next desk.

Comment: Yeah, I did try breaking @bind-Value, but that didn't help me with the test. Let me try your code in a sandbox. Thanks for helping!